# Create a New Customizable scrollbar that will pass to a new element

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, scroll

I hope this is possible, I already have the code but the problem is how can I pass my scrollbar in the arrow so it will be the arrow, not the scroll bar.
Here is my code

```js
let scrollHeight = document.querySelector('.scrollbar-container').clientHeight
let scrollOffset = document.querySelector('.scrollbar-container')
let scrollBarStyle = document.querySelector('.scroll-bar-style')
let scrollBarPaddle = document.querySelector('.paddle')

let scrollArrow = document.querySelector('.arrow')

console.log(scrollHeight)

// set the scroll bars 
scrollBarPaddle.style.height = `${scrollOffset.scrollHeight - scrollHeight}px`
scrollBarPaddle.style.top = `${20}px`
scrollArrow.style.top = `0px`
scrollBarStyle.style.height = `${scrollHeight}px`

// scrollbar movement
scrollOffset.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
  // document.querySelector('.arrow').innerHTML = scrollOffset.scrollTop
  console.log(scrollOffset.scrollTop)
  scrollArrow.style.top = `${scrollOffset.scrollTop}px`
  scrollBarPaddle.style.top = `${ scrollOffset.scrollTop + 20 }px`

}, {
  passive: true
})
console.log(scrollOffset.scrollHeight)
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.scrollbar-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  gap: 10px 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.scrollbar-container .box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: gray;
}

.scroll-bar-style {
  width: 50px;
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.scroll-bar-style .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.scroll-bar-style .paddle {
  width: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollbar-container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="scroll-bar-style">

  <div class="arrow">
    <ion-icon name="arrow-down-outline"></ion-icon>
  </div>

  <div class="paddle">

  </div>

</div>
```

Yes, this is working but I want to remove that scrollbar and pass it to my customize scrollbar. If someone helps me this will be my a large thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question, are you just looking to customize a scrollbar or make a complete new one ?

Comment: make a new one scrollbar. something like that.

Comment: Can I do that sir?

Comment: Probably yes but I was honestly looking for a fast answer with [webkit scrollbar](https://caniuse.com/?search=webkit%20scrollbar)

Comment: Nah this is customizing...not creating new scrollbar.

Comment: Yes indeed, this is why I asked my first question and didn't make an answer. Your question is complexe and need events to make your scrollbar works. You may need mousedown, mousemove and mousedown to catch events on your scrollbar.

Comment: As far I can imagine. I believe I can do it with trying to suit as background none the scrollbar and make `z-index: -1` at the `paddle` I think.. this might help you..cause I'm trying it out..

Comment: @Cédric one thing I want to ask..I don't know if this exist.. Can I position absolute the `-webkit-scrollbar` ?  cause if i can do that I already find my answer.